# snowpipe to load internal stage to permanent tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

suggest me the notification channel for snow pipe method to load internal stage (input files land in internal stage) to permanent tables,

--whenever files land in internal stage the snowpipe should start and load to internal table
-- no external stage or tables should involved

SHOW pipes;

Comment: This is not possible with internal stages as there is no notification service that can recognise when files land in an internal stage. You could create a SP that comes close to mimicking this process e.g. by scheduling it to run every minute - but in that case you might as well just get the SP to load the data - no need/benefit to use pipes